# NET-SNMP and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, net-snmp

I am writing a C++ SNMP server using a NET-SNMP library. I read the [documentation](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/docs/README.thread.html) and still got one question. Can multiple threads sharing single snmp session and using it in procedures like `snmp_sess_synch_response()` simultaneously, or I must init and open new session in each thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when I am trying to `snmp_sess_synch_response()` from two different threads using the same opaque session pointer simultaneously, one of three errors always occures. The first is memory access violation, the second is endless `WaitForSingleObject()` in both threads and the third is heap allocation error.

I suppose I can treat this as an answer, thus sharing single session between multiple threads is unsafe, because using it in procedures like `snmp_sess_synch_response()` simultaneously will cause an errors.

P.S. Here is the piece of code of described before:

```
void* _opaqueSession;
boost::mutex _sessionMtx;

std::shared_ptr<netsnmp_pdu> ReadObjectValue(Oid& objectID)
{
    netsnmp_pdu*    requestPdu = snmp_pdu_create(SNMP_MSG_GET);
    netsnmp_pdu*    response = 0;
    snmp_add_null_var(requestPdu, objectID.GetObjId(), objectID.GetLen());

    void* opaqueSessionCopy;
    {
        //Locks the _opaqueSession, wherever it appears
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(_sessionMtx);
        opaqueSessionCopy = _opaqueSession;
    }

    //Errors here!
    snmp_sess_synch_response(opaqueSessionCopy, requestPdu, &response);

    std::shared_ptr<netsnmp_pdu> result(response);
    return result;
}

void ExecuteThread1()
{
    Oid sysName(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0");
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            boost::thread::interruption_pont();
            ReadObjectValue(sysName);
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {}
}

void ExecuteThread2()
{
    Oid sysServices(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.7.0");
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            boost::thread::interruption_pont();
            ReadObjectValue(sysServices);
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {}
}

int main()
{
    std::string community = "public";
    std::string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    snmp_session    session;
    {
        SNMP::snmp_sess_init(&session);

        session.timeout = 500000;
        session.retries = 0;

        session.version = SNMP_VERSION_2c;
        session.remote_port = 161;

        session.peername = (char*)ipAddress.c_str();

        session.community = (u_char*)community.c_str();
        session.community_len = community.size();
    }

    _opaqueSession = snmp_sess_open(&session);

    boost::thread thread1 = boost::thread(&ExecuteThread1);
    boost::thread thread2 = boost::thread(&ExecuteThread2);

    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds::seconds(30));

    thread1.interrupt();
    thread1.join();

    thread2.interrupt();
    thread2.join();

    return 0;
}
```